# i2cdetect-ed address shifting with each detect

Tags: raspbmc, raspbian-wheezy, i2c

I'm trying to use use [an Adafruits 0.56" 7-Segment Backpack](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-led-backpack/0-dot-56-seven-segment-backpack) (with Holtek HT16K33 chip).
My RasPi Rev2 is running Raspbmc.

What's causing me problems is that the **address** of the chip (single one on the i2c bus) is **constantly changing**. Example:

```
pi@raspbmc ~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- 76 --                         
pi@raspbmc ~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- 72 -- -- -- -- --                         
pi@raspbmc ~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: 70 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Because of that, I can't use the chip/backpack.

Ideas how to fix this?

Comment: 1) Loose wiring, or 2) the chip requires address bits to be tied low/high and you've left them floating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address is set by soldering **pads on the back of the backpack**. Maybe you placed it somewhere where those **pads got shorted**. There is a **tutorial** on how to ***change the address*** [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-led-backpack/changing-i2c-address).

My guess is, to be on the safe side, solder all possible connections to get a maximum value of 0x77. That way a shorting shouldn't change the address (although it might still damage both your Pi and the backpack!)

Comment: Shorting all the solder-jumpers did the trick -- now the address is a fixed 0x77.